# Strength Modeling on logic data type possible?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

Strength modeling is possible on nets (eg `wire`), but is it possible for variables? (eg `logic`).

Comment: Is this what you're asking about?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_(mathematical_logic)

Comment: no @duffymo it is in SystemVerilog programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nets are not data types. Nets can have a data type, including `logic` as well as strength. Strength is only used when there are multiple drivers on a net. Variable cannot have multiple drivers. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/usage-var#reply-42240